# BreakpointObserver not firing

Tags: angular, observable, breakpoints

I have set up my `BreakpointObserver` as follows, but it doesn't seem to be firing when ever my page loads. My page is always in the mobile orientation. How can I fix it?

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Breakpoints, BreakpointState, BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  isMobile: Observable<BreakpointState> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset);

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<div *ngIf="!isMobile | async">is not mobile</div>

<div *ngIf="isMobile | async">is mobile</div>
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot `.matches` earlier...

Comment: Try to initialize isMobile observer in constructor or in preferred in ngOnInit.

Comment: @PatrykBrejdak how do you do that? Can you please show me an example?

Comment: It's simple, just move `this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset);` to `ngOnInit` like `ngOnInit() { this.isMobile = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset); }`

Comment: Like this? https://pastebin.com/YBwVH6aV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `isMobile` is an `Observable` which will unwrap into a value some like this:

```
{
  "matches": true,
  "breakpoints": {
    "(max-width: 599px) and (orientation: portrait)": true,
    "(max-width: 959px) and (orientation: landscape)": false
  }
}
```

Place a `!` before it will always make it false to `*ngIf`

The unwrapped object will have a `matches` property, however, which is a `boolean`. So you can use that.

Try this instead:

```
<div *ngIf="!(isMobile | async)?.matches">is not mobile</div>

<div *ngIf="(isMobile | async)?.matches">is mobile</div>
```

Also, change your `HomeComponent` implementation to initialize `isMobile` in `ngOnInit` as that's what is followed as a common practice:

```
export class HomeComponent {
  isMobile: Observable<BreakpointState>;

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.isMobile = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset);
  }

}
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-breakpoint-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Sorry that was typo in my original question. I get this error message: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of null`. Why is `isMobile` null in my case?

Comment: Because `isMobile` will resolve asynchronously. And till it resolves, you can't use `.matches` on it. Use the safe operator(?) for the same. I'll update my answer and the StackBlitz.

Comment: Yeah. I've updated my answer and the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-breakpoint-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Can you update your StackBlitz to include a scenario with ngOnInit()?

Comment: I've updated the answer and the StackBlitz again. Please check.